# Непонятный синтаксис в JS { enter }

Tags: javascript, node.js

Что означает такой тип записи? Я немного недопонимаю.

```
const Stage = require('telegraf/stage');
const { enter } = Stage;

bot.start(async (ctx) => enter('first'))
const secondScene = new Scene('second')
```

// Возможно здесь мы обращаемся через enter('first') к объекту Scene('first');
// Верны ли мои догадки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const { enter } = Stage;
```

эквивалент

```
const enter = Stage.enter;
```

`enter` в данном случае имя одного из полей объекта `Stage`

```
const myObject = {
    first: 1,
    second: 2,
    third: 3
}

const {first, third} = myObject;
```

то же самое, что и:

```
const first = myObject.first;
const third = myObject.third;
```

Получим локальные константы `first` и `third`

Comment: Дополнение: это называется object deconstruction